# Most general two parameter monotonically increasing functional form between 2 points

Tags: functions

I have had this question I have been thinking about, but I am not sure on the best way to proceed. Basically given an interval, $I = [0,a]$, I want to define a function $f(x,p_1,p_2)$ where $x \in I$ and $p_1,p_2$ are parameters. Furthermore, $f(0)=0$ and $f(a)=1$.

Now, the 1 parameter version of this is just a threshold function. However the two parameter version should be more interesting.

Any ideas on what form will allow for the greatest variety of functions? I do not have any other constraints except for the monotonicity.

The solution I came up with is to assume:

$f = mx^2 +nx + p$. The first constraint implies that $p=0$ giving:

$f = mx^2 +nx$ and then the second implies $1=ma^2+na$. Thus there is only 1 free parameter. Is this even possible? I suppose I should then assume a cubic form but I would then need to enforce monotonicity somehow...

Any feedback would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to start with four parameters, so that the two equations $f(0)=0$ and $f(a)=1$ leave two degrees of freedom.

If you use a cubic (and, for simplicity, take $a=1$), the result is
$f(x) = c_1 x + c_2 x^2 + (1 - c_1 - c_2) x^3$.   This is monotone increasing
on $[0,1]$ if $(c_1, c_2)$ is in the region shown here in blue:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote if I could. However I now have doubts if a cubic would fit my current problem like you said. Essentially what I am trying to do is fit data to a function that I cannot evaluate directly, so I want to do a grid search over some parameter space and pick the best function that helps some problem the most - although there is no way to "learn" these parameters except for guessing since I dont have any data points to fit. I do worry about 4 parameters being too many combinations to guess though. Did you mean to fit a quintic function?